# How to pass multiple parameter to ajax and from ajax to controller in mvc4?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

**My First Question**

Hi i have 4 fields in my view FromDate,ToDate,CustomerName, Count.
I want to pass the value of FromDate,ToDate,CustomerName to single Action and  have to get the value in Count Textbox. Help me to solve this problem.

**My second question**

```
  public JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(Guid customerID, DateTime fromdate,DateTime Todate)
    {
        var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == customerID select sc.SalesOrderID).Count();
        return Json(salescount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The above code get the total SalesOrder count of customer now what i need is i want to get the sales order count of customer(which i select in Dropdown) between FromDate(Which i select in view) and ToDate(which i select in view). how i alter this query for my requirement.

**My View**

```
  <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">

         @Html.Label("FromDate", new { @class = "control-label" })   
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})

                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToDate)     
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToDate, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text" })

                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName)     
        @Html.DropDownList("CustomerID","Select")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName)
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.count)     
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.count, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.count)
                </div>
            </div>
```

**My jquery**

```
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.0.js"></script>
   <script type ="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $.ajax(

        //url: "/VisitorsForm/GetCustomers",
        '@Url.Action("GetCustomers","Report")', {
            type: "GET",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#CustomerID').append('<option value="' + value.CustomerID + '">' + value.DisplayName + '</option>');
                });

            }
        });
});

  $("#CustomerID").change(function () {
    //$('#ContactID').empty();
    alert("hhh");
    var req = {
        CustomerID: $("#CustomerID").val(),
        FromDate: $("#FromDate").val(),
        ToDate: $("ToDate").val()
    }

    $.ajax(
        '@Url.Action("GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer", "Report")', {
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(req),
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve Email.' + ex);
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#count").val(data);
            }
        });

});

</script>
```

**My Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]

    public ActionResult NewExistingCustomer( CustomerViewModel cvm)
    {
        ViewBag.CustomerID = new SelectList(db.Customers, "CustomerID", "DisplayName");

      return View();

    }

    public JsonResult GetCustomers()
    {

        return Json(db.Customers.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public JsonResult GetSalesOrderCountByCustomer(Guid customerID, DateTime fromdate,DateTime Todate)
    {
        var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID == customerID select sc.SalesOrderID).Count();
        return Json(salescount, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    }}
```

Comment: Your javascript object properties names should be in the same case as your parameters in action. Please correct it and let us know  your `SalesOrder` class to know about the query. And also let us know if your controller action is being hit and you are getting the values passed.

Comment: ok lets i have a check

Comment: also pls correct some indentation of code.

Comment: Manoj i change the properties names same as like parameter name and if i run the application it hit only the get customer action and also its not working . its shows alert message fail to retrieve

Comment: Do you use Firebug or Chrome developer tools for debugging javascript? Can you let us know what is the error from server? Are you sure you are setting the values properly in client side?

Comment: yes sure wait i will show the error

Comment: [Error][1]

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgB4v.jpg my error when i inspect my element

Comment: From what ever i could see, you are not sending the date values properly. Make those date parameters as strings and see if your action gets hit.

Comment: no its not working it just hit the get customer and load the customer list in Dropdown and if i select the customer name it showing fail to retrieve

Comment: Keep your chrome developers tool open. Change your dropdown. Go to network tab there and see the response. Server should have sent you the details. Click on that request to see the full error details.